# Clicking button on webpage using Selenium Python Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a 'bot' to buy a graphics card. I've downloaded a pre-made script, and i'm trying to adjust to my needs.

Script take me to the site in Firefox, finds the button I am trying to look for using the following code:

`findAllCards = soup.find('button', {'class': 'Button__StyledButton-iESSlv dJJJCD Button-dtUzzq kHUYTy'})`

This works. However, when I an trying to click the button, I am unable to as I have no idea what I am suppose to find here:
 `driverWait(driver, 'css', '.space-b center')`

Webpage I'm using to test is:
https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/gaming/console-gaming/controllers/xbox-wireless-controller-carbon-black-10211565-pdt.html

Full code here:

```
driver.get(url)
    while True:
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
        wait2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
        try:
            findAllCards = soup.find('button', {'class': 'Button__StyledButton-iESSlv dJJJCD Button-dtUzzq kHUYTy'})
            if findAllCards:
                print(f'Button Found!: {findAllCards.get_text()}')

                # Clicking Add to Cart.
                time.sleep(.3)
                print('Click')
                driverWait(driver, 'css', '.space-b center')
                print('Click1')
                time.sleep(2)
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `findAllCards` above returns 3 web elements, not 1.  Assuming you are trying to click on the **Add to Basket** button:

```
findAllCards = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='product-actions']//div[@data-component='add-to-basket-button-wrapper']//button")

findAllCards.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick response. I've tried the above and this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: woops, my mistake.  had the incorrect ID.  Try again

Comment: try:
            findAllCards = soup.find('button', {'class': 'Button__StyledButton-iESSlv dJJJCD Button-dtUzzq kHUYTy'})
            if findAllCards:
                print(f'Button Found!: {findAllCards.get_text()}')

                # Clicking Add to Cart.
                time.sleep(.3)
                print('Click')
                findAllCards = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='product-main']//div[@data-component='add-to-basket-button-wrapper']//button")
                findAllCards.click()
                print('Click1')
                time.sleep(2)

Comment: Get rid of the soup.find piece and all the rest of it.  Just try with the code I provided above after you reach that URL.  See if it works

Answer (score 0):

Some odd thing with element to  be interactable.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
try:
    elem=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(.,'Add to basket')]")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks, will give this a try tomorrow and report back